# Missing early boot logs before busybox-syslog starts up

Tags: kernel, syslog

Problem: Kernel logs that occurred before syslogd starts up, do not get appended to my syslog.

System Description:
I have syslogd starting up about 5s into the boot sequence. I have a script that appends to /dev/kmesg that runs about 2 seconds into the boot sequence. It runs before syslogd starts up.

I'm running klogd to send kernel logs to syslog, but it only sends the kernel logs that occurred after syslogd starts up.

I'm missing the kernel logs from my script in syslog, since syslogd is not started up at the time the script runs.

I'm seeing all kernel logs after 5 seconds in my syslog. If I simply append to /dev/kmsg after 5s of bootup, I see the logs go into syslog.

My /etc/syslog.conf configures everything to go into syslog like so

*.* /path/to/syslog

I need to get klogd to log the existing contents of kmsg ring buffer to syslog, not just stuff that got appended to /dev/kmsg after klogd ran. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

After starting `klogd`, run a second copy of it in *one-shot mode* (`klogd -o`). It will read and process the existing messages in the kernel message buffer, and then exit.

Starting the long-lived instance of `klogd` first should ensure that no messages are lost.

If you cannot do that (e.g. if you have a very old version of `klogd` or one that comes from `busybox` or similar embedded-system toolkit), then how about doing something like:

```
if [ -e /var/log/dmesg.boot ]; then
    mv /var/log/dmesg.boot /var/log/dmesg.prevboot
fi
dmesg > /var/log/dmesg.boot
```

as soon as the root filesystem is writeable?

Comment: I'd thought of this, but the version of klogd I'm using only has the -c and -n options